# Spring Development Like Seam-Gen

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, seam, seam-gen

Do Spring MVC has **project auto creater** same as Seam-Gen?

Answer (score 2):

It has [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) which can generate a project and assist you with creating entities and the service and controller layers of the application. It also assist with the view layer and other features such as security.